# Google App Engine trowing error for PHPExcel

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I want to insert a logo in excel file. In development server it is working perfectly, but after i deployed it to Google App Engine and tried it i am getting error message from App Engine

Error: Server Error

The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.

if i remove the below part from my code it is working fine but with out logo.

```
$tejalogo = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();
  $tejalogo->setName('logo')
        ->setDescription('logo')
        ->setPath('logo.gif')
        ->setHeight(36)
        ->setCoordinates($A.$n)
        ->setOffsetY(4)
        ->setOffsetX(5)
        ->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());
```

i am very confused by this problem.
can anyone help me?

Comment: This may have to do with where 'logo.gif' is stored.  Can you look at the logs to find a more detailed error message?

Comment: in appengine log i got this  "A problem was encountered with the process that handled this request, causing it to exit. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application. (Error code 204)"